# Como obter latitude / longitude de um geoendereço usando Qt c ++ no windows?

Tags: c++, qt, geolocalização, coordenadas

É possível obter as coordenadas (latitude e longitude), de uma localização geográfica usando apenas o endereço, no Qt c ++?

Eu conheço as bibliotecas QGeoCoordinates, QGeoLocation e QGeoAddress, mas eu não sei se é possível obter coordenadas de um endereço através delas.

Toda ajuda é bem-vinda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Através de uma resposta que recebi de um usuário aqui do Stack Overflow em inglês, esta que pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259557/how-to-get-latitude-longitude-from-one-geo-address-using-qt-c-on-windows), pude elaborar uma função que consiga perfeitamente achar as coordenadas através do endereço, segue:

```
QGeoCoordinate MainWindow::getGeoCoordinates() {
    QEventLoop loop;
    QGeoCoordinate qGeoCoord;
    QStringList qGeoSrvList = QGeoServiceProvider::availableServiceProviders();

    for (QString entry : qGeoSrvList) {
        QGeoServiceProvider qGeoService(entry);
        QGeoCodingManager *pQGeoCoder = qGeoService.geocodingManager();

        if ( ( qGeoService.error() == 0 ) && ( qGeoService.errorString().compare("") == 0 ) ) {
            QLocale qLocaleC(QLocale::C, QLocale::AnyCountry);
            pQGeoCoder->setLocale(qLocaleC);

            QGeoAddress qGeoAddr;
            qGeoAddr.setCountry( "país" );
            qGeoAddr.setPostalCode( "cep" );
            qGeoAddr.setCity( "cidade" );
            qGeoAddr.setStreet( "rua, número" );
            qGeoAddr.setState( "estado" );

            QGeoCodeReply *pQGeoCode = pQGeoCoder->geocode(qGeoAddr);

            connect( pQGeoCode, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
            loop.exec();

            if ( pQGeoCode->error() != QGeoCodeReply::NoError ) {
                qDebug() << pQGeoCode->error() << " | " << pQGeoCode->errorString();
                break;
            } else {

                QList<QGeoLocation> qGeoLocs = pQGeoCode->locations();
                for (QGeoLocation &qGeoLoc : qGeoLocs) {
                    qGeoLoc.setAddress(qGeoAddr);
                    qGeoCoord = qGeoLoc.coordinate();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return qGeoCoord;
}
```

**OBS:** Lembrando que no .pro deve ser adicionado QT += positioning location